# CSS: -webkit-mask-image on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, mask

I found an open source project that I was considering using for my website  However the project is dead and it is not fully cross browser compatible.  As a web developer noob, I'm stumped on how to fix it. The issue is with -webkit-mask-image which, according to MDN, is non-standard and therefore not supported on Firefox.

[Here](https://github.com/c2prods/Project-Tyson/) is the project on github and [here](http://www.come.ninja/Project-Tyson/) is a live demo of the code.

The issue is with the page navigation.  Specifically, this is the chunk of code in question.  This works fine on Chrome and Safari.  Doesn't work on Firefox.

```
<button id="btn1" class="active" data-vin="view-home">
    <div class="btn-icon" style="-webkit-mask-image:url(img/icons/user.svg);"></div>
    <div class="label">Home</div>
</button>
```

Any ideas how to modify this to work on Firefox?  I see documentation on MDN for mask and mask-image.  I think this is the answer, but I can't get it to work correctly.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the same look without CSS masking and without altering the images. The images are SVG, so if you open them in your browser and view source, you will get the SVG code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="translate(-374.2178,-62.2364)">
      <path d="m775.103,428.4798c-67.1319,-24.4562 -88.5923,-45.0996 -88.5923,-89.3004 0,-26.526 21.9961,-43.717 29.4945,-66.4511 7.4984,-22.7341 11.8362,-49.6496 15.4417,-69.2289 3.6055,-19.5793 5.0383,-27.1523 6.9992,-48.0136 2.3966,-26.0357 -15.0332,-93.2494 -108.2281,-93.2494 -93.1677,0 -110.6519,67.2136 -108.2009,93.2494 1.9609,20.8613 3.4014,28.4349 6.9992,48.0136 3.5978,19.5788 7.8935,46.4934 15.3872,69.2289 7.4937,22.7355 29.5217,39.9251 29.5217,66.4511 0,44.2009 -21.4604,64.8443 -88.5923,89.3004 -67.377,24.5106 -111.1149,48.6808 -111.1149,65.7566 0,17.0485 0,80 0,80l512,0c0,0 0,-62.9515 0,-80 0,-17.0485 -43.7651,-41.2187 -111.1148,-65.7566z"
      />
    </g>
</svg>
```

To work cross browser, you can now insert that code into your button and color it with the `fill` CSS property.

#### Example

```css
button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  fill: #6F6F74;
  outline: none;
}
button.selected svg {
  fill: #318CFA;
}
button:hover svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="active selected" data-vin="view-home">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="translate(-374.2178,-62.2364)">
      <path d="m775.103,428.4798c-67.1319,-24.4562 -88.5923,-45.0996 -88.5923,-89.3004 0,-26.526 21.9961,-43.717 29.4945,-66.4511 7.4984,-22.7341 11.8362,-49.6496 15.4417,-69.2289 3.6055,-19.5793 5.0383,-27.1523 6.9992,-48.0136 2.3966,-26.0357 -15.0332,-93.2494 -108.2281,-93.2494 -93.1677,0 -110.6519,67.2136 -108.2009,93.2494 1.9609,20.8613 3.4014,28.4349 6.9992,48.0136 3.5978,19.5788 7.8935,46.4934 15.3872,69.2289 7.4937,22.7355 29.5217,39.9251 29.5217,66.4511 0,44.2009 -21.4604,64.8443 -88.5923,89.3004 -67.377,24.5106 -111.1149,48.6808 -111.1149,65.7566 0,17.0485 0,80 0,80l512,0c0,0 0,-62.9515 0,-80 0,-17.0485 -43.7651,-41.2187 -111.1148,-65.7566z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
  Selected
</button>

<button id="btn1" class="active" data-vin="view-home">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="translate(-374.2178,-62.2364)">
      <path d="m775.103,428.4798c-67.1319,-24.4562 -88.5923,-45.0996 -88.5923,-89.3004 0,-26.526 21.9961,-43.717 29.4945,-66.4511 7.4984,-22.7341 11.8362,-49.6496 15.4417,-69.2289 3.6055,-19.5793 5.0383,-27.1523 6.9992,-48.0136 2.3966,-26.0357 -15.0332,-93.2494 -108.2281,-93.2494 -93.1677,0 -110.6519,67.2136 -108.2009,93.2494 1.9609,20.8613 3.4014,28.4349 6.9992,48.0136 3.5978,19.5788 7.8935,46.4934 15.3872,69.2289 7.4937,22.7355 29.5217,39.9251 29.5217,66.4511 0,44.2009 -21.4604,64.8443 -88.5923,89.3004 -67.377,24.5106 -111.1149,48.6808 -111.1149,65.7566 0,17.0485 0,80 0,80l512,0c0,0 0,-62.9515 0,-80 0,-17.0485 -43.7651,-41.2187 -111.1148,-65.7566z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
  Not selected
</button>
```

Comment: Can't say that I love the idea of pasting the contents of the svg directly into the code, but it mostly seems to work.  What about the blue border that is left around the outside of the button when you change selected buttons?

Comment: @DizzyBay - It's not as clean, that is true. In this case, it seems to be used on three buttons and the markup will be easy to maintain. Use `  outline: none;` on the button to remove that blue outline when clicked (I added to the example)

Comment: @DizzyBay a cleaner way of using this technique would be to use svg symbols: https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

Comment: @misterManSam Ah, looks much better.  Let me play around with it a bit when I get home later tonight and see if this will work.

Comment: @VincentOrback Thx for the tip.  I will look into this as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I finally was able to get this solution to work in my website.  I don't love the solution (embedding the svg contents in the webpage) but it did solve the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support mask-image. It’s a non-standard so not sure when it will be either. So you should probably look for another solution like `background-image` or an inline `<img>`-tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-image#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Oh yeah... I forgot that I did see that mask-image was also non-standard.  Thanks for the reminder.

I briefly looked into this approach (using background-image or <img> tags), but wasn't sure how to receive the desired effect (without writing a bunch of javascript code).  Could you clarify more?

Answer (score 0):

**SVG mask for SVG elements** , **Support for all Browsers**.

```
<mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <rect y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gradient)" />
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".4" fill="gray" />
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".3" fill="white" />
  ...
</mask>

.item {
  mask: url(#masking);
  }
```

Reference from http://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/fsdbu . For more specific, https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-masking-1-20140213/#the-mask-image .